# How to calculate leaderboard at the end of every month

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a table which keeps track of how many votes an employee received in a month

```
[<Placement id: 1, employee_id: 1, month: "2014-02-01", votes: 2>, 
<Placement id: 2, employee_id: 1, month: "2014-01-01", votes: 2>, 
<Placement id: 3, employee_id: 2, month: "2014-02-01", votes: 1>,
<Placement id: 4, employee_id: 2, month: "2014-01-01", votes: 3>
<Placement id: 5, employee_id: 3, month: "2014-02-01", votes: 9>]
```

I now want to keep track of what position they were in at the end of every month (most votes in position 1 etc).

I'm going to add the column :position to the Placements model like so:

```
[<Placement id: 1, employee_id: 1, month: "2014-02-01", votes: 2, position: 2>, 
<Placement id: 2, employee_id: 1, month: "2014-01-01", votes: 2, position: 2>, 
<Placement id: 3, employee_id: 2, month: "2014-02-01", votes: 1, position: 3>,
<Placement id: 4, employee_id: 2, month: "2014-01-01", votes: 3, position: 1>
<Placement id: 5, employee_id: 3, month: "2014-02-01", votes: 9, position: 1>]
```

I have something like this in the heroku scheduler:

```
if Date.today == Date.today.end_of_month
 Placement.each_with_index do |p, index|
  p.update_attributes(position: index+1)
 end
end
```

How would I compare votes from all the same months? This compares all months

Comment: you can do it with cron job.

Comment: How does this 'position' system work? Based on what is a position calculated? Why are there multiple entries for a single employee in a single month? Why can there be a position multiple times (position 1 for id 4 and 5)? I would just add a table that holds the positions and sum of votes after one month. But a lot would depend on details of how this actually works.

Comment: Where are there multiple entries for a single employee in a single month?

Comment: Position is based on most votes per month

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To run on a single month and update position you could:

```
def update_single_month(month)
  Placement.where(month: month).order('votes desc').each_with_index do |placement, position|
    placement.position = position
    placement.save!
  end
end
```

To run on all existing data, you need to simply know for which months you already have data:

```
def update_all_months
  Placement.select(:month).group(:month).each { |r| update_single_month(r.month) }
end
```